# Lifetime of emitter in ObservableOnSubscribe

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I am using RxJava for listening an event of Bluetooth adapter. The bluetooth listener may be active for long duration like for few hours. My question is how long the emitter is valid and I can send events though it?

My code is:

```
Class BlutoothObserver{

    ObservableEmitter emitter;
    BlutoothObserver(){
        ...
        starListeningBluetoothDevice();
    }

    public Observer getObserver(){
        return Observable.create(e -> {
            emitter =e;
        });
    }

    public void bluetoothCallback(){
        ...
        emitter.onNext();
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should stay alive as long as you do not call `onComplete()` on `emitter`.

You will want to be careful with how you define `getObserver()` though.  Right now you are creating a new `Observable` every time.  So if you called `getObserver()` twice in a row it would return different `Observable` instances and only the last one returned would be of use.  I would just create a field for the Observable and set it at construction time.